# Buttons of the same size in tilepane javafx

Tags: java, button, javafx, size

Hi guys I m completely new with GUIs... so far all of my programs where text based. I ve just started and im using JAVAFX. 
I wanted to recreate a telephone keypad. It should have 4 rows of 3 buttons each and each button should have its related number along with its letters. And it does. But the size of the buttons is not the same.

[image]

I mean… since i'm using a tilePane the buttons occupy the same amount of pixels (or at least I guess it is like that), but the actual an visible size of the buttons is different because every button takes only the size that it needs in order to display its contents. I stored the buttons in an array. Is there a way to make them all of the same size of the biggest one?

```
public class PhoneKeyboard extends Application
{

    Button buttons [];
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        // Create the set of necessary buttons.
        buttons = new Button[12];
        fillButtons(buttons);
        //Create the grid for the buttons.
        TilePane pane = new TilePane();
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
        pane.setPrefColumns(3);
        pane.setMaxWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);// Use the pref size as max size to make sure there will be the expected size
        pane.setVgap(5.0);// to set ome spacing between each tile of the pane.
        pane.setHgap(5.0);
        //Put the buttons on the pane (layout);
        pane.getChildren().addAll(buttons); 
        // JavaFX must have a Scene (window content) inside a Stage (window)
        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(pane), 300,400);// In order to use the pfer size of the pane, the tile Pane doesn"t have to be the root in the scene. Therefore we created a scene with a stack pane containing our tile pane as the root. 
        stage.setTitle("Keyboard");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        // Show the Stage (window)
        stage.show();
}
```

Comment: It would be easier for us to re-create your problem, if the code you’ve provided included the `fillButtons` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Button has a maximum width and maximum height which are just big enough to hold the Button’s content.  Most layouts, including TilePane, won’t make child nodes larger than their maximum size.

If you want each button to be capable of being made larger, set its maximum width and height, after calling `fillButtons`:

```
for (Button button : buttons) {
    button.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
}
```